# Understanding the Aux pattern in Scala Type System

Tags: scala, shapeless

This question may be asked and answered before, but I would like to understand this with an example and I could not reason out where the Aux pattern might be helpful! So here is the trait:

```
trait Foo[A] {
  type B
  def value: B
}
```

Why do I have a type that is kind of bound to the return type of the value function? What do I achieve doing this? In particular, where would I use such patterns?

Comment: `type B` works just like A, only that it's named and can be referenced, contrary to A.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Imagine a typeclass for getting the last element of any tuple.

```
trait Last[A] {
  type B
  def last(a: A): B
}

object Last {
  type Aux[A,B0] = Last[A] { type B = B0 }

  implicit def tuple1Last[A]: Aux[Tuple1[A],A] = new Last[Tuple1[A]] {
    type B = A
    def last(a: Tuple1[A]) = a._1
  }

  implicit def tuple2Last[A,C]: Aux[(A,C),C] = new Last[(A,C)] {
    type B = C
    def last(a: (A,C)) = a._2
  }

  ...
}
```

The type `B` always depends on the type `A`, that's why `A` is an input type of the typeclass and `B` is an output type.

Now if you want a function that can sort any list of tuples based on the last element you need access to the `B` type in the same argument list. That's the main reason, in the current state of Scala, why you need the `Aux` pattern: currently it's not possible to refer to the `last.B` type in the same parameter list as where `last` is defined, nor is it possible to have multiple implicit parameter lists.

```
def sort[A,B](as: List[A])(implicit last: Last.Aux[A,B], ord: Ordering[B]) = as.sortBy(last.last)
```

Of course you can always write `Last[A] { type B = B0 }` out in full, but obviously that becomes very impractical very quickly (imagine adding a couple more implicit parameters with dependent types, something that's very common with Shapeless); that's where the `Aux` type alias comes in.

Comment: You don't technically _need_ the `Aux` pattern to refer to `last.B` in the same parameter list; it's just preferred because it's much less verbose than `implicit last: Last[A] { type B = B0 }, ord: Ordering[B0]`.

Comment: @breadmenace Well yes, technically you never need the Aux type alias. I assume 'Aux pattern' to refer to the broader pattern in which the type alias is needed for having an acceptable syntax.

Comment: newb question - why isn't the return type of the implicit defs (the ones using Aux) inferred from the computed value?

Comment: @user2359636 I'm pretty sure they actually are inferred if you let them, but it's bad practice not to add type annotations to implicits. I think dotty has already outlawed non-annotated implicits.

Answer (score 13):

Starting Scala 3 [dependent types](https://twitter.com/milessabin/status/1072825307181264896?s=20) are supported within the **same** parameter list, which seems to make `Aux` pattern unnecessary, [for example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/9Su9Mxq6TZSEv104jzzT5w), Jasper-M's snippet simplifies to

```
trait Last[A]:
  type B
  def last(a: A): B

given [A]: Last[Tuple1[A]] with
  type B = A
  def last(a: Tuple1[A]) = a._1

given [A, C]: Last[(A,C)] with
  type B = C
  def last(a: (A,C)) = a._2

def sort[A](as: List[A])(using last: Last[A], ord: Ordering[last.B]) = as.sortBy(last.last)

sort(List(("ffle",3), ("fu",2), ("ker",1)))
// List((ker,1), (fu,2), (ffle,3))
```

Note the usage of `last.B` where `last` is a value coming from the same parameter list in

```
def sort[A](as: List[A])(using last: Last[A], ord: Ordering[last.B])
```