# Force dependent types resolution for implicit calls

Tags: scala, implicit, type-level-computation, path-dependent-type

I have a wrapper trait :

```scala
trait Wrapper[T] {

  ...
  type Own[F[_]] <: OwnThing[F]
  def ask[F[_]](implicit own: Own[F])

}
```

And different implementations, here is an example :

```scala
class CombinedWrapper[A, B](wrapperA: Wrapper[A], wrapperB: Wrapper[B]) extends Wrapper[(A, B)] {
  override type Own[F[_]] = SomeOwnThing[(A, B), wrapperA.Own[F], wrapperB.Own[F]]
  override def ask[F[_]](implicit own: Own[F]) = ???
}
```

But the implicit resolution will not resolve the path-dependent types, therefore not finding any implicits.

Is there a way to force the resolution of path-dependent types?
As for now, I just think of them as variables but at the type level.

Edit : 
A more complete version:

```scala
trait Wrapper[T] {

  ...
  type Own[F[_]] <: OwnThing[F, T]
  def ask[F[_]](implicit own: Own[F])

}

sealed trait OwnThing[F[_], A]

trait SomeOwnThing[F[_], A, B, ThingA <: OwnThing[F, A], ThingB <: OwnThing[F, B]] extends OwnThing[F, (A, B)] {
  def underlyingA: ThingA
  def underlyingB: ThingB
}

class CombinedWrapper[A, B](wrapperA: Wrapper[A], wrapperB: Wrapper[B]) extends Wrapper[(A, B)] {
  override type Own[F[_]] = SomeOwnThing[F, A, B, wrapperA.Own[F], wrapperB.Own[F]]
  override def ask[F[_]](implicit own: Own[F]) = ???
}
```

Edit2: A non-working example

```scala
trait SimpleOwn[F[_], A] extends OwnThing[F, A]

class SimpleWrapper[T] extends Wrapper[T] {
    override type Own[F[_]] = SimpleOwn[F, T]
    override def ask[F[_]](implicit own: Own[F]) = ???
  }

val combined = new CombinedWrapper[String, Int](new SimpleWrapper[String], new SimpleWrapper[Int])
type Id[A] = A

//Simple case for base types
implicit val intOwn: SimpleOwn[Id, Int] = new SimpleOwn[Id, Int]
implicit val stringOwn: SimpleOwn[Id, String] = new SimpleOwn[Id, String]

//Should combine the two above
implicit def composeOwnIds[A, B, ThingA <: OwnThing[Id, A], ThingB <: OwnThing[Id, B]](implicit aOwn: ThingA, bOwn: ThingB): SomeOwnThing[Id, A, B, ThingA, ThingB] = new SomeOwnThing {
  override def underlyingA: ThingA = aOwn
  override def underlyingB: ThingB = bOwn
}

//Should work but cant find implicit
combined.ask[Id]
```

Edit3: For me, the root of the problem is in `CombinedWrapper` at the type member definition. I think Scala does not resolve the path-dependent-types use in the definition.

I can say this because

```scala
new SimpleWrapper[String].ask
```

does compile

Comment: Something about your example code is really messed up. The syntax `type A[F[_]] <: B[F[_]]` isn't even valid. Furthermore `wrapperA.Own[F]` does not make sense. `wrapperA` is a value, `Own[F]` is a type. What you want might be `Wrapper[A]#Own[F]`?

Comment: Is there an error or just the complexity?

Comment: Sorry, pressed submit a little too early. See my updated comment.

Comment: Also `SomeOwnThing` has to be a subtype of `OwnThing` as defined in `Wrapper`, but `SomeOwnThing` has no higher kinded type parameter.

Comment: In general it would be better to show us a complete example (even though it doesn't compile, so we can try make it). I am missing some definitions (e.g. `SomeOwnThing`).

Comment: Yes, thank's for pointing out the existential I've misused. I did not add SomeOwnThing definition for simplicity but I will.

Comment: I'd also like to see a code example of the problem you're having, i.e. where you say the implicit resolution should work but doesn't.

Comment: @MarkusAppel `wrapperA.Own[F]` does make sense: https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/13/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-13-path-dependent-types.html

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I stand corrected. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly fix couple of typos

```
//class CombinedWrapper[A, B](wrapperA: Wrapper[A], wrapperB: Wrapper[B]) extends Wrapper[(A, B)] {
  class CombinedWrapper[A, B](val wrapperA: Wrapper[A], val wrapperB: Wrapper[B]) extends Wrapper[(A, B)] { ...

//implicit val intOwn: SimpleOwn[Id, Int] = new SimpleOwn[Id, Int]
  implicit val intOwn: SimpleOwn[Id, Int] = new SimpleOwn[Id, Int] {}
//implicit val stringOwn: SimpleOwn[Id, String] = new SimpleOwn[Id, String]
  implicit val stringOwn: SimpleOwn[Id, String] = new SimpleOwn[Id, String] {}

//implicit def composeOwnIds[A, B, ThingA <: OwnThing[Id, A], ThingB <: OwnThing[Id, B]](implicit aOwn: ThingA, bOwn: ThingB): SomeOwnThing[Id, A, B, ThingA, ThingB] = new SomeOwnThing {
  implicit def composeOwnIds[A, B, ThingA <: OwnThing[Id, A], ThingB <: OwnThing[Id, B]](implicit aOwn: ThingA, bOwn: ThingB): SomeOwnThing[Id, A, B, ThingA, ThingB] = new SomeOwnThing[Id, A, B, ThingA, ThingB] { ...
```

Then standard way to debug implicits is to resolve them manually (maybe specifying some type parameters explicitly) and see compile errors.

```
new SimpleWrapper[String].ask
new SimpleWrapper[Int].ask
```

are actually

```
new SimpleWrapper[String].ask[Id](stringOwn)
new SimpleWrapper[Int].ask[Id](intOwn)
```

If you try

```
combined.ask[Id](composeOwnIds(stringOwn, intOwn))
```

you'll have

```
Error: type mismatch;
 found   : App.intOwn.type (with underlying type App.SimpleOwn[App.Id,Int])
 required: App.combined.wrapperB.Own[App.Id]
Error: type mismatch;
 found   : App.stringOwn.type (with underlying type App.SimpleOwn[App.Id,String])
 required: App.combined.wrapperA.Own[App.Id]
```

If you try

```
combined.ask[Id](composeOwnIds[String, Int, SimpleOwn[Id, String], SimpleOwn[Id, Int]](stringOwn, intOwn))
```

you'll have

```
Error: type mismatch;
 found   : App.SomeOwnThing[App.Id,String,Int,App.SimpleOwn[App.Id,String],App.SimpleOwn[App.Id,Int]]
 required: App.combined.Own[App.Id]
    (which expands to)  App.SomeOwnThing[App.Id,String,Int,App.combined.wrapperA.Own[App.Id],App.combined.wrapperB.Own[App.Id]]
```

If you replace

```
val combined = new CombinedWrapper[String, Int](new SimpleWrapper[String], new SimpleWrapper[Int])
```

with

```
val strWrapper = new SimpleWrapper[String]
val intWrapper = new SimpleWrapper[Int]
val combined = new CombinedWrapper[String, Int](strWrapper, intWrapper)
```

then

```
combined.ask[Id](composeOwnIds[String, Int, strWrapper.Own[Id], intWrapper.Own[Id]](stringOwn, intOwn))
```

will give

```
Error: type mismatch;
 found   : App.SomeOwnThing[App.Id,String,Int,App.strWrapper.Own[App.Id],App.intWrapper.Own[App.Id]]
    (which expands to)  App.SomeOwnThing[App.Id,String,Int,App.SimpleOwn[App.Id,String],App.SimpleOwn[App.Id,Int]]
 required: App.combined.Own[App.Id]
    (which expands to)  App.SomeOwnThing[App.Id,String,Int,App.combined.wrapperA.Own[App.Id],App.combined.wrapperB.Own[App.Id]]
  combined.ask[Id](composeOwnIds[String, Int, strWrapper.Own[Id], intWrapper.Own[Id]](stringOwn, intOwn))
```

The thing is that although `combined.wrapperA` is `strWrapper` and `combined.wrapperB` is `intWrapper` but types `combined.wrapperA.Own[Id]` and `strWrapper.Own[Id]` are different and types `combined.wrapperB.Own[Id]` and `intWrapper.Own[Id]` are different too.

For example if you have

```
trait MyTrait { type T }
val mt = new MyTrait {}
val mt1 = mt
```

then values are equal but types are different

```
//  implicitly[mt.T =:= mt1.T] // doesn't compile
//  implicitly[mt1.T =:= mt.T] // doesn't compile
```

Try to modify `CombinedWrapper` adding more type parameters and specify them with specific dependent types at call site

```
  trait Wrapper[T] {
    type Own[F[_]] <: OwnThing[F, T]
    def ask[F[_]](implicit own: Own[F])
  }

  sealed trait OwnThing[F[_], A]

  trait SomeOwnThing[F[_], A, B, ThingA <: OwnThing[F, A], ThingB <: OwnThing[F, B]] extends OwnThing[F, (A, B)] {
    def underlyingA: ThingA
    def underlyingB: ThingB
  }

//  class CombinedWrapper[A, B](val wrapperA: Wrapper[A], val wrapperB: Wrapper[B]) extends Wrapper[(A, B)] {
//    override type Own[F[_]] = SomeOwnThing[F, A, B, wrapperA.Own[F], wrapperB.Own[F]]
//    override def ask[F[_]](implicit own: Own[F]) = ???
//  }

  class CombinedWrapper[A, B, OwnA[F[_]] <: OwnThing[F, A], OwnB[F[_]] <: OwnThing[F, B]](
    val wrapperA: Wrapper[A] { type Own[F[_]] = OwnA[F] }, 
    val wrapperB: Wrapper[B] { type Own[F[_]] = OwnB[F] }
  ) extends Wrapper[(A, B)] {
    override type Own[F[_]] = SomeOwnThing[F, A, B, OwnA[F], OwnB[F]]
    override def ask[F[_]](implicit own: Own[F]) = ???
  }

  trait SimpleOwn[F[_], A] extends OwnThing[F, A]

  class SimpleWrapper[T] extends Wrapper[T] {
    override type Own[F[_]] = SimpleOwn[F, T]
    override def ask[F[_]](implicit own: Own[F]) = ???
  }

//  val combined = new CombinedWrapper[String, Int](new SimpleWrapper[String], new SimpleWrapper[Int])
  val strWrapper = new SimpleWrapper[String]
  val intWrapper = new SimpleWrapper[Int]
  val combined = new CombinedWrapper[String, Int, strWrapper.Own, intWrapper.Own](strWrapper, intWrapper)

  type Id[A] = A

  implicit val intOwn: SimpleOwn[Id, Int] = new SimpleOwn[Id, Int] {}
  implicit val stringOwn: SimpleOwn[Id, String] = new SimpleOwn[Id, String] {}

  implicit def composeOwnIds[A, B, ThingA <: OwnThing[Id, A], ThingB <: OwnThing[Id, B]](implicit aOwn: ThingA, bOwn: ThingB): SomeOwnThing[Id, A, B, ThingA, ThingB] = new SomeOwnThing[Id, A, B, ThingA, ThingB] {
    override def underlyingA: ThingA = aOwn
    override def underlyingB: ThingB = bOwn
  }

  combined.ask[Id] // compiles

  new SimpleWrapper[String].ask  // compiles
```

---

Using `Aux` type

```
  trait Wrapper[T] {
    type Own[F[_]] <: OwnThing[F, T]
    def ask[F[_]](implicit own: Own[F])
  }

  object Wrapper {
    type Aux[T, Own0[F[_]] <: OwnThing[F, T]] = Wrapper[T] { type Own[F[_]] = Own0[F] }
  }

  class CombinedWrapper[A, B, OwnA[F[_]] <: OwnThing[F, A], OwnB[F[_]] <: OwnThing[F, B]](
    val wrapperA: Wrapper.Aux[A, OwnA], val wrapperB: Wrapper.Aux[B, OwnB]
  ) extends Wrapper[(A, B)] {
    override type Own[F[_]] = SomeOwnThing[F, A, B, OwnA[F], OwnB[F]]
    override def ask[F[_]](implicit own: Own[F]) = ???
  }
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I have moved the type member as a type parameter. This is annoying as the resulting types cannot be read by humans, but it works.
I am very much interested in your `MyTrait` example. Can you explain why the two types are different, please?

Comment: @Merlin Regarding type parameter vs. type member, that's the reason to use `Aux` pattern (see update) http://gigiigig.github.io/posts/2015/09/13/aux-pattern.html http://www.vlachjosef.com/aux-pattern-evolution/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900674/understanding-the-aux-pattern-in-scala-type-system

Comment: @Merlin Regarding `MyTrait`, here is standard way to create (values of) [path-dependent types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693067/what-is-meant-by-scalas-path-dependent-types) `class A { class B}` `val a1: A = new A` `val a2: A = new A` `val b1: a1.B = new a1.B` `val b2: a2.B = new a2.B` Whether two values are equal depends on implementation of `equals` but types for different prefixes are different always.

Comment: @Merlin Well, for `mt`, `mt1` even references are equal. But types are different anyway. `mt1` could be `var` and after `val mt = new MyTrait {}`
`var mt1 = mt` we could change `mt1 = new MyTrait {}`. Firstly references were equal, now they are different but that's not the reason to change type of the `var` :) So types were different from the very beginning.